# Outlook 2007 Add-in in Outlook 2003

Tags: outlook-addin

Just a quick questions..
I have made an outlook add-in for 2007 version and when I tested it with version 2003 it did not seem to work. 
Is there any special procedure I need to follow to enable to add-in in Outlook 2003 or it won't work at all? I hope I don't have to create a new one for 2003.

### Thanks,

SL

Comment: Please add some detail to your question. What does the add-in do? What errors are you getting? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to an add-in created using VSTO.

When you create an add-in for Office 2007 the referenced Interop Assemblies will be the ones associated with Office 2007 and this is the main reason for your add-in not to work on Office 2003.

One alternative will be to reuse the custom add-in code but build it against Office 2003 Interop assemblies. This will work if you're not using any functionality inherent to Office 2007.

IIRC, a VSTO add-in developed for Office 2003 will possibly work on Office 2007 without change, but never the other way around.

Comment: Yea.. I have created the addin using VSTO. 
Thanks for your answer. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: ya its right create add-in project in 2003 and use pia 2003 for 2003 outlook and pia 2007 for 2007 outlook - Kumaran